# IHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName VS Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT")

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

In an ASP.NET Core Web API application, built using .NET 6, is `IHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName` and  `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT")` always the same? If not, under what circumstances can they differ?

To elaborate a bit, my question is about the `IHostEnvironment` instance which is injected in `Startup` constructor by the .NET. Something like this `Startup(IHostEnvironment env)`.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for the full documentation on how the environment is determined

The gist of it is that both DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT and ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT are read to determine the environment. Depending on which builder you use, one can take precedence over the other.

> The DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT value overrides ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT when WebApplicationBuilder is used. For other hosts, such as ConfigureWebHostDefaults and WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder, ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT has higher precedence.

Alternatively, it is also possible to provide the environment as command line parameter as such: `dotnet run --environment Production`

Finally, it is also possible to provide the environment as an argument to the builder itself:

```
WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
{
    EnvironmentName = Environments.Staging
});
```

though I have to say I've never had to do that. All in all, considering how many possible sources there are, it's definitely not a great idea to read the environment variable instead of using the IHostingEnvironment.

One last thing. The environment defaults to Production, which your environment variable won't do unless you explicitly use a default.

Answer (score 1):

> IHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName and
> Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT") always the
> same?

Before jumping into your main question it needs a brief background but I promise it would enlight you what you are curious about.

IHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName:

Generally, [IHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostenvironment?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) of asp.net core older than 6 which is derived from [IHostEnvironment Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.internal.hostingenvironment?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) that returns us information about the hosting environment an application is running in by reading information from [launchSettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson) as you can see below:

[image]

[image]

Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable():

From dotnet 6  [IHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostenvironment?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) not longer using and it replaced by [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariables?view=net-7.0#system-environment-getenvironmentvariables) which also Retrieves  environment variable names from [launchSettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson) that is derived from Environment static class as you can see below:

[image]

[image]

Therefore, [IHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostenvironment?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) older than dotnet6 and  [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariables?view=net-7.0#system-environment-getenvironmentvariables) of later than dotnet6 both provides us the information of application environment. For instance, whether its dev, prod or stage.

> If not, under what circumstances can they differ?

DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT In IHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName:

Actually, Depending on [DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#environments) and [ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#environments) we may experience divergent result. Because [DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#environments) value overrides [ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#environments)  when you would used in asp.net core version older than 6 as it overrides; Thus, you still can get the environment variable name exactly. As you can see below:

[image]

DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT In Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable():

However, it  doesn't act accrdingly in  asp.net core 6 and later version unlike older than asp.net core 6. Because [ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#environments) has higher precedence over [DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#environments) and you would ended up completely different result. For [DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#environments) you would get null [EnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariables?view=net-7.0#system-environment-getenvironmentvariables) which you can see below:

[image]

**Note:** In summary, they both works for getting application environment varibale information while runnning. But denpending on DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT precedence their value differ. If you still would like to know more details on it you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#environments)